# Ajax Call not calling the Controller Action Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm not able to make ajax call to the controller action method which returns the json object.
Also, I want to pass the integer-CheckID to the method.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance!

```
***View***

<script type="text/javascript">

function showCheckImage(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    var CheckID = dataItem.ID;

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetDeferredCheckImage", "Customer")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {deferredCheckID: CheckID },
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

        success: function(result) {
            //var imageObj = result;
            alert('Loaded Image Object!');
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert('Error occurred while loading the image object.');
        }
    });
}
```

```
**Controller Method**

[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetDeferredCheckImage(int deferredCheckID)
    {
        try
        {
            QCEventLogger.Log($"Gathering deferred check image for check ID: {deferredCheckID}", LogType.Default);
            var response = new AjaxGetDeferredCheckImageViewModel(deferredCheckID);
            QCEventLogger.Log($"Result of service call to gather deferred check image.  check ID: {deferredCheckID}. Success: {response.Success}", LogType.Default);

            var DeferredCheckImageObject = response.ImageCheckObject.DeferredCheckImages.FirstOrDefault();

            return Json(DeferredCheckImageObject, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var failureResponse = new AjaxGetDeferredCheckImageViewModel() { Success = false };
            QCErrorLogger.Log($"Failure trying to gather deferred check image for check ID: {deferredCheckID}", ex);
            return Json(failureResponse, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);                
        }
    }
```

Comment: well... for one, your data doesn't match your content type.

Comment: Remove `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` - ( your not stringifying the data)

Comment: Thank you. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call might be like this,

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetDeferredCheckImage", "Customer")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { deferredCheckID: CheckID },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            //var imageObj = result;
            alert('Loaded Image Object!');
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert('Error occurred while loading the image object.');
        }
    });
```